# Android daemon thread test

Tags: android, multithreading, spawn

I'm testing Think in Java's Multi thread like this in Android:

```
private void testDeamon(){

    Thread d = new Daemon();
    System.out.println(
            "d.isDaemon() = " + d.isDaemon());


    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


public class Daemon extends Thread {
    private static final int SIZE = 10;
    private static final String TAG = null;
    private int i = 9000;

    private Thread[] t = new Thread[SIZE];
    public Daemon() { 
        setDaemon(true);
        start();
    }
    public void run() {
        for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
            t[i] = new DaemonSpawn(i);
        for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
            System.out.println(
                    "t[" + i + "].isDaemon() = " 
                            + t[i].isDaemon());
        while(true) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Deamon running..."+ i--);
            if (i==0) 
                break;

            yield();
        }
    }

    class DaemonSpawn extends Thread {
        public DaemonSpawn(int i) {
            System.out.println(
                    "DaemonSpawn " + i + " started");
            start();
        }
        public void run() {
            while(true) 
                yield();
        }
    }
}
```

1. Why the spawn daemon's outcome is false, so the spawn of a daemon is not daemon here
2. Why the Daemon thead keep running after the Android application exit? According to the TIJ, the JVM exit after all non-deamon thread killed and the deamon thread exit too. So the JVM is not shutdown after application destroyed? Thanks.

Comment: I think you might have to use `setDaemon(true);` to make them daemons, so that isDaemon() will return true instead of false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't answer the first question. They should be daemons too (http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/thinking_in_java/TIJ315_005.htm)
For Android purposes, daemon threads or non-daemon threads are moot. Your app's process never exits: It either remains in the background or it gets killed at some point.

Your second question:
What do you mean by "... Android application exit..."? Apps don't 'exit', they just go into the background and, if the OS deems it necessary, they may get killed.

In other words, when your app goes into the background, it doesn't exit. It keeps running in the background (until it gets killed at some point).

Comment: "Android application exit" means I exit a app and the main Activity get destroyed.

Comment: Thanks! So Does every App has a JVM?

Comment: It depends, but, generally: yes.

Comment: It depends on your app's design. You could share your app's Activities (through Intents and such) and they could be running on another one's process (unlikely); Your app's Activities can run on more than one process (using the android:process attribute); You app runs in its own process (most common). This means that the most common case is that each app runs in its own process, using its own DalvikVM.

Comment: Thanks! The android:process is helpful.

Comment: Don't overuse the android:process attribute. You should have a very very good reason for using this attribute and even a better reason why *not* using this attribute wouldn't work. :)

Comment: Thank you for the tip. So I think the IPC may be a better approach:)